# FLASH AS3: Save Dialog Box in HTML not Display

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Good daY!.

I'm slightly newbie in Flash AS3. And I need a little help for my problem. I created a photobooth that can save and captured image. However, the save dialog box working in .swf file. But when I tried to run it in HTML the save dialog box its not displaying anymore. Also I already publish the .swf file to HTML file.

My problem:
What should I do to display or show the save dialog box in HTML.

Here's my code:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(817, 530);
        bitmapData.draw(this);

        var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
        var byteArray:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);

        var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();

        fileReference.save(byteArray,"Pic.jpg");
```

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: You should make sure `fileReference.save` is called inside a listener for an user action (click, key pressed...).

Comment: @Kodiak, the code above are already inside in the function event listener of button. I didn't just include it in here.